# Random Forests (regression) - Rank variable importance based on performance in different models (with different response variables)

Tags: random-forest, importance

I am running regression random forests.

My original database has 138 potential predictors (*x.1, x.2 ... x.138*) and 4 different response variables (*a*, *b*, *c* and *d*). The response variables are different ways to quantify the same phenomenon (complexity in the architecture of a plant).

After carrying out a [feature selection](https://topepo.github.io/caret/recursive-feature-elimination.html) for every response variable, I finished with 19 predictors. Some predictors were kept exclusively on one model, while others were kept in more than one model:

---

RF_a (selected features): *x.1, x.2, x.3, x.4, x.5, x.6, x.7, x.8, x.9*
RF_b (selected features): *x.1, x.6, x.7, x.8, x.10, x.11, x.12*
RF_c (selected features): *x.3, x.7, x.8, x.9, x.13, x.14, x.15, x.16, x.17, x.18*
RF_d (selected features): *x.6, x.7, x.8, x.9, x.19*

---

So, for example, predictor *x.6* is common to models RF_a, RF_b and RF_d, while predictor *x.19* was kept only for model RF_d.

For each of the final models (RF_a, RF_b, RF_c, RF_d) I have the **% of variance explained** by the model, the **mean of squared residuals**, and I can also compute the **importance** of each predictor variable as explained [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/importance). These **Importance** measures of the predictors are specific to each model and indicate the differences (in percentaje) generated in the MSE of the model after permuting each predictor variable.

I am trying to generate a ranking of the Importance of the variables throughout all the models, to get an idea of which variables were the most relevant throughout the modeling process. Averaging the "variable importance" values of a predictor among all the models in which that predictor appears makes no sense since a predictor can be the more important in a group of poor models. So I wonder **if there is a way to weigh the "variable Importance" by some measure of the overall performance of each model**.

Some data and the models!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lH-qn14EHHTrtqm5-4TB7be2HZGDvN2R/view?usp=sharing

```
    library("randomForest")
    ## ##########################
    ## ##########################
    Data <- as.data.frame(
        data.table::fread("For_stackoverflow.txt"))

    ## ##########################
    y <- Data[, "a"]
    x <- Data[, c("x.1", "x.2", "x.3", "x.4",
                  "x.5", "x.6", "x.7", "x.8",
                  "x.9")]
    Fita <- randomForest(x = x, y = y,
                         mtry = 3,
                         ntree = 20000,
                         importance = T)
    Fita
    importance(Fita, type = 1)

    ## ##########################
    y <- Data[, "b"]
    x <- Data[, c("x.1", "x.6", "x.7", "x.8",
                  "x.10", "x.11", "x.12")]
    Fitb <- randomForest(x = x, y = y,
                         mtry = 3,
                         ntree = 20000,
                         importance = T)
    Fitb
    importance(Fitb, type = 1)

    ## ##########################
    y <- Data[, "c"]
    x <- Data[, c("x.3", "x.7", "x.8", "x.9",
                  "x.13", "x.14", "x.15", "x.16",
                  "x.17","x.18")]
    Fitc <- randomForest(x = x, y = y,
                         mtry = 3,
                         ntree = 20000,
                         importance = T)
    Fitc
    importance(Fitc, type = 1)

    ## ##########################
    y <- Data[, "d"]
    x <- Data[, c("x.6", "x.7", "x.8",
                  "x.9", "x.19")]
    Fitd <- randomForest(x = x, y = y,
                         mtry = 2,
                         ntree = 20000,
                         importance = T)
    Fitd
    importance(Fitd, type = 1)
```

Comment: Fun problem! (+1) I think your intuition that the naive mean is misleading is absolute correct; please see my post below for more details and a sketch of a solution.